# How to create a column with the most recent data in a Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data frame for the GDP of various countries. Each row is a different country and each column after the 4th column is a year's data from 1960 to 2020 for each country. I am trying to create a new column that has only the most recent year's GDP data as some countries have certain years and other do not. I am unable to come up with a function or method to only keep/extract the most recent year's data for each country. I am not really sure how to approach it either so not be able to try anything that has been of progress.

Any help or how to go about it would be appreciated.

Code Implemented to clean original file thus far:

```
gdp_annual_df = pd.read_excel("API_NY.GDP.MKTP.CD_DS2_en_excel_v2_1622079.xls",sheet_name = "Data" )
gdp_annual_df.columns = gdp_annual_df.iloc[2]
gdp_annual_df = gdp_annual_df.drop([0,1,2])
```

Data File From = https://data.worldbank.org/indicator/NY.GDP.MKTP.CD

[image: First part of the Data Frame]
[image: Second part of the Data Frame]

This is the Data Frame (sorry not sure how to add it properly/neatly)

```
    2   Country Name    Country Code    Indicator Name  Indicator Code  1960.0  1961.0  1962.0  1963.0  1964.0  1965.0  ... 2011.0  2012.0  2013.0  2014.0  2015.0  2016.0  2017.0  2018.0  2019.0  2020.0
3   Aruba   ABW GDP (current US$)   NY.GDP.MKTP.CD  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... 2.549721e+09    2.534637e+09    2.701676e+09    2.765363e+09    2.919553e+09    2.965922e+09    3.056425e+09    NaN NaN NaN
4   Afghanistan AFG GDP (current US$)   NY.GDP.MKTP.CD  5.377778e+08    5.488889e+08    5.466667e+08    7.511112e+08    8.000000e+08    1.006667e+09    ... 1.780429e+10    2.000160e+10    2.056107e+10    2.048489e+10    1.990711e+10    1.936264e+10    2.019176e+10    1.948438e+10    1.910135e+10    NaN
5   Angola  AGO GDP (current US$)   NY.GDP.MKTP.CD  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... 1.117897e+11    1.280529e+11    1.367099e+11    1.457122e+11    1.161936e+11    1.011239e+11    1.221238e+11    1.013532e+11    9.463542e+10    NaN
6   Albania ALB GDP (current US$)   NY.GDP.MKTP.CD  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... 1.289077e+10    1.231983e+10    1.277622e+10    1.322814e+10    1.138685e+10    1.186120e+10    1.301969e+10    1.514702e+10    1.527808e+10    NaN
7   Andorra AND GDP (current US$)   NY.GDP.MKTP.CD  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... 3.629204e+09    3.188809e+09    3.193704e+09    3.271808e+09    2.789870e+09    2.896679e+09    3.000181e+09    3.218316e+09    3.154058e+09    NaN
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
262 Kosovo  XKX GDP (current US$)   NY.GDP.MKTP.CD  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... 6.701698e+09    6.499807e+09    7.074778e+09    7.396705e+09    6.442916e+09    6.719172e+09    7.245707e+09    7.942962e+09    7.926108e+09    NaN
263 Yemen, Rep. YEM GDP (current US$)   NY.GDP.MKTP.CD  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... 3.272642e+10    3.540134e+10    4.041524e+10    4.320647e+10    3.697620e+10    2.808468e+10    2.456133e+10    2.759126e+10    NaN NaN
264 South Africa    ZAF GDP (current US$)   NY.GDP.MKTP.CD  7.575397e+09    7.972997e+09    8.497997e+09    9.423396e+09    1.037400e+10    1.133440e+10    ... 4.164189e+11    3.963327e+11    3.668294e+11    3.509046e+11    3.176205e+11    2.963573e+11    3.495541e+11    3.682889e+11    3.514316e+11    NaN
265 Zambia  ZMB GDP (current US$)   NY.GDP.MKTP.CD  7.130000e+08    6.962857e+08    6.931429e+08    7.187143e+08    8.394286e+08    1.082857e+09    ... 2.345952e+10    2.550306e+10    2.804551e+10    2.715065e+10    2.124335e+10    2.095476e+10    2.586814e+10    2.700524e+10    2.306472e+10    NaN
266 Zimbabwe    ZWE GDP (current US$)   NY.GDP.MKTP.CD  1.052990e+09    1.096647e+09    1.117602e+09    1.159512e+09    1.217138e+09    1.311436e+09    ... 1.410192e+10    1.711485e+10    1.909102e+10    1.949552e+10    1.996312e+10    2.054868e+10    2.204090e+10    2.431156e+10    2.144076e+10    NaN
```

Comment: please post data in clear text and not as an image

Comment: Also, what have you tried so far on the code. can we see the code

Answer (score 0):

Create list of lists for each row then loop through and pick last non-null value.`enter code here`

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,np.nan,np.nan], [1,np.nan, 3,4,np.nan],[1,np.nan, 3,4,5]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'])
latest = []
for lst in df.values.tolist():
    latest.append([l for l in lst if not pd.isnull(l)][-1])
df['latestValue'] = latest
```

Input dataframe:

```
   a    b  c    d    e
0  1  2.0  3  NaN  NaN
1  1  NaN  3  4.0  NaN
2  1  NaN  3  4.0  5.0
```

Output:

```
   a    b  c    d    e  latestValue
0  1  2.0  3  NaN  NaN          3.0
1  1  NaN  3  4.0  NaN          4.0
2  1  NaN  3  4.0  5.0          5.0
```

Comment: Thanks, I was able to do it another way but I will try this way too.